# pandas dataframe merging when columns are not same

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have two dataframes with no common column name. I have to merge them one after another. Example: df1 is

```
A      B
102   880
```

and df2 is:

```
C      Count
C      5
D      598
E      14
F      38
```

One after another as in:

```
A      B
102   880 

C      Count
C      5
D      598
E      14
F      38
```

For this i tried converting dataframe to csv and then merging them but couldn't acheive it. Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain better how you want to merge the DataFrames?, what are you expecting to have after the merge?

Comment: Hmm, you're trying to merge df1 and df2 into a single dataframe? What columns would this new dataframe have? 'A' and 'B'? What about the column names of df2? You want them to be added as data rows into the new dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting a result as this:

```
   Count
A    102
B    880
C      5
D    598
E     14
F     38
```

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{ 'A': 102, 'B': 880 }])
df1 = df1.transpose()
df1.columns = ['Count']
df2 = pd.DataFrame([('C', 5), ('D', 598), ('E', 14), ('F', 38)] ,columns =['C', 'Count']).set_index('C')

result_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```